# Migrations and Update Database in Entity Framework for Dynamic connection string

Tags: entity-framework

I'm having 2 databases one for managing clients and other for managing application data. I'm trying to implement multi-tenancy application using EF code first approach where the database will be created on the fly it doesn't exist. Now tenant databases are creating fine but, database migrations are not performing since the connection string is passing programmatically. Please tell me how to do Database migrations for tenant databases where the connection string are set programmatically at runtime.

Thanks,
Naveen

Answer (score 0):

Check out `IDesignTimeDbContextFactor<T>`

Microsoft doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.design.idesigntimedbcontextfactory-1?view=efcore-2.1

Example: https://www.benday.com/2017/12/19/ef-core-2-0-migrations-without-hard-coded-connection-strings/